# Spams compilation error: unknown argument: '-funsafe-loop-optimizations-mmacosx-version-min=10.7'

Tags: matlab, gcc, compilation, mex

I want to use the SPAMS package to do some sparse coding project. I use Matlab 2013b on Mac. When I run `compile.m`, the following error is shown:

```
compilation of: -I./linalg/ -I./decomp/ -I./prox/ -I./dictLearn/ dictLearn/mex/mexTrainDL.cpp
clang: error: unknown argument: '-funsafe-loop-optimizations-mmacosx-version-min=10.7' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
mex: compile of ' "dictLearn/mex/mexTrainDL.cpp"' failed.
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like two valid option names `-funsafe-loop-optimizations` and `-mmacosx-version-min=10.7` that were run together. Edit `compile.m` and search for these strings, and add a space either after `-funsafe-loop-optimizations` or before `-mmacosx-version-min=10.7`.